# How do I output my results in GUI C#

Tags: c#, string, user-interface, oop, complex-numbers

I am trying to add two complex numbers from an GUI. I create 4 text-boxes - 2 are real number and 2 are imaginary numbers. I created an enter button. So, when I press enter it will display my results in a MessageBox.

I need help with displaying my results. I need it to display it in a way like this: 3 + 5i (where 3 is the sum of the real numbers and 5 is the sum of the imaginary number. I need the "i" to show up as well). I am getting a red line under this part: sum = ("{0} + {1}i",x ,y);

edited: So, now I want to do subtraction of the complex number. It shows no result for subtraction. Is it because I am not subtracting any vaule?

Here is my code:

```
    private double rPart1; // real number
    private double iPart1; // imaginary number
    private double rPart2; // real number
    private double iPart2; // imaginary number
    double x;
    double y;
    double call;
    double r;
    string sum;

    public string add()
    {
        rPart1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxReal1.Text);
        iPart1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxImaginary1.Text);
        rPart2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxReal2.Text);
        iPart2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxImaginary2.Text);

        x = rPart1 + rPart2;
        y = iPart1 + iPart2;

        sum = ("{0} + {1}i",x ,y);

        return sum;
    }

    public string sub()
    {

        x = rPart1 - rPart2;
        y = iPart1 - iPart2;

        subtract = (x + "-" + y + "i");

        return subtract;

    }

    private void buttonEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sum = add();
        subtract = sub();
        MessageBox.Show("The addition is: " + sum
            + "\nThe subtraction is: " + subtract);
    }
```

Comment: This `sum = (x + " + " + y + "i");` works fine for me and should output the same as yours.

Answer (score 3):

you need to write:

```
sum = string.Format("{0} + {1}i", x, y);
```

Btw. the .Net Framework 4.0 and onwards do have a complex number struct built in:

[Complex Numbers in .Net 4.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `String.Format` method:

```
string result = String.Format ("{0} + {1}i", x, y) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in nice way.make a struct in your project  like :

```
public struct MyNumber
{
public MyNumber(double rPart1,double iPart1,double rPart2,double iPart2){//Set fields value}
    private double rPart1;
    private double iPart1;
    private double rPart2;
    private double iPart2;
    public  double X { get { return rPart1 + rPart2 ; } }
    public  double Y { get { return iPart1 + iPart2; } }
    public  string Sum(string format)
    {
       return string.Format(format, X, Y);
     }
  }
```

and in your code

```
public string add()
{
   MyNumber number=new MyNumber(Convert.ToDouble(textBoxReal1.Text),Convert.ToDouble(textBoxImaginary1.Text),Convert.ToDouble(textBoxReal2.Text),Convert.ToDouble(textBoxImaginary2.Text));
   return number.Sum(custom format);
}
```